# Why does not my count method return false when it is supposed to?

Tags: java, oop, return, boolean, counter

I have coded a class where you have a start and an end as inputs, and where a counter counts either up or down depending on whether the start value is smaller or bigger than the end value. When the counter has reached the end value, it should return false, if not it should return true.

When I run this in a junit test my professor has made, it says "After reaching the end value, the count() method should return false". I don't understand what is wrong with code.

```
public class UpOrDownCounter {

    private int end;
    private int counter;
    private int start;
    private int increment;

    UpOrDownCounter(int start, int end){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.counter = start;

        isValid();

        if(start<end) {
            this.increment = 1;
        }
        else {
            this.increment = (-1);
        }
    }

    public void isValid() throws IllegalArgumentException{
        if(this.start == this.end) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the start value can't be the same as the end value");
        }
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public boolean count() {
        counter += increment;
        if(this.counter == end) {
            this.counter == 0;
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "[counter = " + counter + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        UpOrDownCounter c = new UpOrDownCounter(3, 5);
        System.out.println(c.toString());
}
```

Comment: Without seeing that junit test there is not much we can do. The code itself looks fine. What is the expected behavior of the counter _after_ end is reached? The current implementation will only one time return false. If again `count` is called, it will increment again until infinity and never stop. Is that expected? I think not

Comment: Thank you! I found the error:)

Comment: If you finally have a working solution, please post it as an Answer and accept that!

Answer (score 1):

What happens to `this.increment` if `start == end`? We need to call isValid(), so that the counter doesn't blow past either end of the range.
Change your constructor to:

```java
UpOrDownCounter(int start, int end) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.counter = start;

    isValid();

    if(start<end) {
        this.increment = 1;
    } else {
        this.increment = (-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems equal start and end point is an invalid scenario. Still this never hurts.

Comment: Keep in mind that ```isValid()``` never actually gets called

Comment: Thank you! How do I call isValid()?

Comment: Tank you so much! I'm trying to write a main method, but when I print the toString it only says that counter = 3. Do you know how to change my code so I can see that the counter counts?

Comment: ```while (count()) print()```